# How to export MUI DataGrid data by select columns?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I have a MUI DataGrid and I want to be able to select the column header and export it. Right now you can check the rows that you want to export by clicking on the checkbox.

[screenshot of checking rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwVRQ.png)

You can also filter out columns by going into the filters and unchecking any columns that you don't want to see.

But I want to be able to select the column header for a column, like how you can do it in excel and export that specific column.

I have looked into the code in the MUI data grid repo but I haven't found anything helpful yet.